# Event tracking & Audicente is not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm implementing google analytics on my site. I'm trying to track events but I really don't know why I don't get any event nor any session information in the audience menu.

However I have checked the real time menu overview and I can see sessions on my website but I can't see any event tracking.

The code I'm using for tracking events is:

```
function social(type, action, url) {
        console.log('Clicked')
    ga('send', 'social', type , action, url);
}
```

I know this function is executed because I can see the console.log

Any tip with the sessions and event tracking problem? Thanks

**EDIT:**
It was a problem with the date selection on the google analytics.

Solved. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, events are found under Behavior menu and not Audience. And second, you are using ga('send', 'social', ...), so they will be available as Social Interactions under "Acquisition > Social > Plugins" and not in Events.

Comment: I don't have any data there either

Comment: Do you have a webpage where this is implemented?

Comment: Yes of course http://netbeast.co

Comment: The implementation on the webpage is definitely correct. So it should work. The realtime section of GA doesn't report Social interactions. Go to Audience Overview and check how delayed is the regular data coming in to your account. Check "Acquisition > Social > Plugins" after waiting those number of hrs and you should see the numbers for these events.

Comment: Okey I'll try. Thanks

Comment: You can also verify with GA Debugger (free plugin for Chrome), where you see the hit go through to GA. It def looks like the hit is valid.